# $form->input checkbox foreign key other than name. cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I add label for input other than name or more than name, eg

```
<label for="category_id">Name - Initial</label>
  <input id="category" />
```

I tried this.

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_id', array('multiple'=>'checkbox','label' => 'Category.initials'));
```

This is what I want to achieve.

```
 <label for="category_id">Name - Initial</label>
      <input id="category" />
```

ANSWER FROM GOOGLE!

You can create a virtual field[1] in the model.

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(User.last_name, ", ", User.first_name)'
);
```

Then, I believe (haven't tried this) that you could specify full_name
as the model's display field:

```
public $displayField = 'full_name';
```

Comment: I need to have Name Lastname on checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it you can set the label to anything you want by passing it a string:

```
array( 'label' => 'Name - Initial');
```

Or you could build that string out of some pre-existing variables:

```
array( 'label' => $name . ' . ' . $initial);
```

Or have I misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hmm, not really, It can ti use Model.field but it seems not to work.

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like: 'label' = $user['User']['lastname'] . ' - ' . $user['User']['firstname']?  (Having set user to the result of a database query first, naturally...)